# Line $(x,y,z) = (1+s,-2+s, 2s)$ is parallel to the line...

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new to this forum so I'm sorry if I broke some rules or conventions.
I'm also new to math so it might be basic.

I have to questions:

- The line $(x,y,z) = (1 + s, -2 + s, 2s)$ is parallel with the line $x+3=(2y-1)/2=(z-3)/2$. True or false? (and why?)
- Decide the equation for the plane who have the line $x/2 = y + 1 = (z-2)/3$ and the point $(1,1-1)$

I got stuck on the first task. I don't know what to do with $x+3=(2y-1)/2=(z-3)/2$ and $x/2 = y + 1 = (z-2)/3$

Please help me :)

Comment: Did you read any basic book on 3d geometry?

Answer (score 1):

1) Clearly, a directing vector for the line has the vector $\;(1, 2/2,1/2)\;$ as a directing vector. It is collinear to the vector $\;(1,1,2)$.

2) Find two points on the line, and write the plane with equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$ passes through the three given points.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But i don't know how to think about $x+3=(2y-1)/2=(z-3)/2$ and $x/2 = y + 1 = (z-2)/3$ . What is the first thing to do? And what to convert it to? What kind of information can i get out of it?

Comment: For the first line, I said the directing vector is obvious (the coefficients of $x$, $y$, $z$). For the second line , you need to find two points on it. Fix one coordinate  and compute the other two. Repeat for a second point.